# Cocos2dx Update and Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

After updating Cocos2dx and Xcode I started receiving the error: Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). It happens when I set the position but I think it has to do with the png image:

```
auto backgroundSprite=Sprite::create("thing.png");
backgroundSprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width /2 +origin.x,visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));
```

I have tried to add this code and image to a different project and it works fine. I have also tried to switch the image file to something else but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to build settings and set: Remove Text Metadata From PNG Files = No

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on desktop, make sure that Target Membership is checked for your `thing.png` and also check form Xcode IDE, file is available in Resource.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got `nullptr` as `backgroundSprite`. Check it before calling `setPosition`.

Comment: Makes sense but do you know why it's null?

Comment: @carebearlife what's your project structure and "thing.png" relative path from it's root? Make sure you specify correct path to image within Sprite::create method.

Comment: The png is in the resources folder. Pretty sure it is the correct path as some of the png files in that folder work but most others don't.